# how to save a plotly graph to excel sheet as an image using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, image, plotly

I created a plotly fig and now, I'm trying to write this fig to excel file as an image.

How can I do this using Python?

```
data = []
data.append(
    go.Bar(
    x=df['id'],
    y=df['normalize energy'], 
    hoverlabel = dict(namelength = -1)
    )
)    
layout = dict(
        title="energy" ,
        xaxis=dict(
            title='id'
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            title='energy [W]',
            titlefont=dict(
                color='rgb(148, 103, 189)'
            ),
            tickfont=dict(
                color='rgb(148, 103, 189)'
            ),
            overlaying='y',
            side='right',
            fixedrange=False
        ),   
        height= 600
    )
fig = go.FigureWidget(data)
fig.layout = layout
fig

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path)
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

I want to add the fig to the excel sheet as well.

Comment: Please provide your code so far. Thanks.

Comment: I added my code, just want to add the fig to the excel file as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`orca`](https://github.com/plotly/orca) (for static image generation) and [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (for writing images into an excel file).

In order to install orca, see the [official doc](https://github.com/plotly/orca#installation).

Then, append this lines to your code:

```py
fig.write_image("fig.png")

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.create_sheet('sheet1',0)
active = wb['sheet1']
active.add_image(Image('fig.png'),'A1')

wb.save('myfile.xlsx')
```